# How do I modify the root XML tag at runtime?

Tags: xml, asp.net-web-api2, xmlserializer

I'm new to XML having usually dealt in JSON for my APIs, so feel free to tell me if I'm trying to reinvent the wheel here.

**Back story**: I'm currently working on an integration that only allows me to have one endpoint to supports multiple requests, i.e. Search, Sell, Update, Cancel. They only support XML, so I cannot use JSON. I determine the type of request from the root XML name, do my work, and then send back a response.

**Problem**: As this is XML, I have to return a strongly-typed object for serialization which prevents me from using many custom classes with `[XmlRoot(ElementName = "blah")]`. Thus, I need to set the root element name at run time to support the different named replies I have to send.

My response class:

```
public class Response
{
    public Errors Error { get; set; }
    public RequestData Request { get; set; }
    public List<Limo> Limos { get; set; }
    public string ReservationID { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string ConfNum { get; set; }
    public string CancelPolicy { get; set; }
}
```

produces a response of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Error>
    <ErrorCode />
    <ErrorSource />
    <ErrorDescription />
  </Error>
  <Request>
    <ServiceType>300</ServiceType>
    <StartDateTime>2015-09-30T09:00:00</StartDateTime>
    <NumPassengers>1</NumPassengers>
    <VehicleType>100</VehicleType>
  </Request>
  <Limos />
</Response>
```

Basically, I need to be able to change `<Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">` into `<SearchReply>`, `<SellReply>`, `<UpdateReply>`, or `<CancelReply>` as needed to end up with something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<SearchReply>
  <Error>
    <ErrorCode />
    <ErrorSource />
    <ErrorDescription />
  </Error>
  <Request>
    <ServiceType>300</ServiceType>
    <StartDateTime>2015-09-30T09:00:00</StartDateTime>
    <NumPassengers>1</NumPassengers>
    <VehicleType>100</VehicleType>
  </Request>
  <Limos />
</SearchReply>
```

Comment: one way I can think of is define new class SearchReply deriving from Response class and use it in response.

Comment: @PankajKapare Thanks. I'll give that a shot and see what happens.

Comment: Not sure though but you may need to register this new type with xmlformatter in your app start event as follows                        var SearchReplyXmlFormatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
SearchReplyXmlFormatter .SetSerializer<SearchReply>(new XmlSerializer(typeof(SearchReply)));

Comment: You're saying that if I go that route, I would have to register an XmlFormatter for each type of reply I'm trying to send?

Comment: May be you need it, may be not. I am not sure. First try dervinging new class, if that doesnt work alone then in addition to that you register formatter.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work alone or with the formatter because I'm back to getting the error `<ExceptionMessage>The type SearchReply was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.</ExceptionMessage>` that I was getting when trying to serialize without a strongly typed method.

Comment: I think its going in right direction. Try adding following attribute on your response class     [XmlInclude(typeof(SearchReply))]

Comment: XmlInclude removes the error, but the root element is back to being Response instead SearchReply

Comment: In that case you can add [XmlRoot(ElementName = "SearchReply")] on SearchReply class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a multi-part fix. I'm not pleased with how I went about getting this to work, but it works none-the-less. I can refactor as I learn more throughout this project.

Based on the suggestions of Pankaj:
I implemented a derived class using `Response` as the base. This wasn't enough as my object was still getting the base `Response` class, but necessary as I needed a separate class for each call to fully implement the next step.

```
public class IntegrationSearchReply : Response
```

Then, I decorated the derived classes to specify the root element name.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "SearchReply", Namespace = "")]
public class IntegrationSearchReply : Response
```

This still wasn't working, so I started researching manually creating my response. The final step I discovered was to change my controller method from returning a `Response` to returning an `HttpResponseMessage`. This enabled me to serialize the object with `XmlSerializer` and set `HttpResponseMessage` content to the serialized object.

Thank you for your help Pankaj!